# Unable to start docker Container from docker-compose - "unknown flag: --iidfile"

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux, docker-image

When I try to run ' docker-compose up"  the command prompt throws the below error :

```
$ docker-compose up
Building tomcat
unknown flag: --iidfile
See 'docker build --help'.
ERROR: Service 'tomcat' failed to build
```

**Below is the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file:**

```
$ cat Dockerfile.dev
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"] `
```

---

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  tomcat:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
  tests:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    command: ["npm", "run", "test"]
```

Do I have something wrong configuration in Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Which Docker version do you have? `docker version`

Comment: I'm using the latest docker binaries.


$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88

Comment: How about docker-compose version?

Answer (score 29):

I faced the same problem when using docker-compose 1.29.1. Downgrading to docker-compose 1.26.2 resolved this problem.

reinstall docker-compose 1.26.2

```sh
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also do `pip install docker-compose==1.26.2`

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Removed docker and installed docker-ce. This helped me to solve the issue.